# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement preprocess-kgptalkie

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I'm trying to add preprocess-kgptalkie  in Python interpreter and I'm receiving these errors

```
Try to run this command from the system terminal. Make sure that you use the correct version of 'pip' installed for your Python interpreter located at '/home/amel/PycharmProjects/pythonProject1/venv/bin/python'.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement preprocess-kgptalkie (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for preprocess-kgptalkie
```

I'm using Python 3.6 and pip 21.2.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `preprocess-kgbtalkie` package on PyPI. However, I was able to find a GitHub repo [here](https://github.com/kgptalkie/preprocess_kgptalkie). Install it with

```
pip install git+ssh://git@github.com/kgptalkie/preprocess_kgptalkie.git
```

Comment: I removed the library. I didnt need it Thanks for your help by the way